# Translation of some pashto idioms to corresponding or nearly equal meaning english idioms

Tags: idioms, idiom-request

These are some of idioms in the Pashto language. I've translated them literally and also tried to explain it, and i'll really appreciate if the corresponding English idiom is provided. The challenging thing here is that I have to find the corresponding English idiom that is which conveys the same meaning, it might have different words or expression it doesnt matter but should be near in meaning; also the exact meaning is also not required, just close enough.  I have explained as I have interpreted them, You are welcome to interpret it differently though. Thank you

[image]
1:Stones that remains in their places are heavy: means one should know its place.

2. The wound of a sword can heal but the one with word can't: said when telling someone to be careful with words like `think before you speak`

3. When the time of death comes, the doctor become blind: means death is inevitable no matter what one does.

4. Be it now, and be it worth 10: said when something is needed now no matter how expensive

5. Skip this one, (I don't know what it means :)

[image]

1. Get out of the village but not from your boundary: means travel far but don't forget your culture and your worth.

2. If the cock doesn't coo, the deaf will not know of morning: means 

3. Those who keep camels as pet should make high doors: means one should deal with the consequences of any act.

4. When I lose it, oh God dont give it to the world: means when I failed or couldnt get it, neither should anyone else.

5. oh Khushah Khattak (An afghan poet), for respected you are respectful while for those without respect you are not worthy of respect: means the worth of a great man is known by people who are good and gives attention.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is, essentially, 10+ questions in one. Questions should be one question at a time, not 10 in one.

Comment: ok but they are the same type of questions. Should I create 10 different posts with same form of question?

Comment: I wouldn't create all 10 questions at once. Try creating one question with two idioms, and see how that goes. Add another question every day or so, and you should get all your translations in about one week. These seem like interesting questions to me; this was only closed because it would be very hard for someone to answer the question in its entirety. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

For the 4th item of the second group, two phrases come to mind, "Sour grapes", from Aesop's fable of the fox who decided that the grapes he was unable to reach must have been sour anyway, and "dog in the manger", meaning that the dog is preventing other animals from eating food it cannot eat itself.

For the second item of the first group there is a phrase that expresses the exact opposite idea: "sticks and stones can break my bones but names will never hurt me". This is sometimes abbreviated to just "sticks and stones".

For the fourth item of the second group, there is "my kingdom for a horse", from Shakespeare's Richard III.

For the third item of the second group, there is "Those who live in glass houses shouldn't throw stones."